# grep the result of some Command(eg. netstat -apn)

Tags: linux, grep, netstat

When you want to know which port was already in use you can use `netstat -apn | grep 27777`. The result is below:

```
> tcp        0      0 ::ffff:43.69.96.68:27777    :::*       LISTEN  79339/java
```

Then you can find which process use the PID 79339.

```
ps -aux | grep 79339
```

Now I wonder if there is a command to find which process uses the port that was already in use.

I tried `ps -aux | grep netstat -apn | grep 18888 | awk -F '[ /]+' '{print $7}'`
but it is no working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First run `netstat` and print out pid like you almost did. Then run `ps` and `grep` pid, using "word" option to avoid grepping parts of the digits (if `pid` is `456` you don't want to match `14567`)

Put that in a bash script and you're done.

```
pid=$(netstat -apn | awk -F '[ /]+' '{print $7}')
ps -aux | grep -w $pid
```